# SQL Server : Insert two stored procedure results into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two stored procedure `sp1` and `sp2`

`sp1` returns results

```
value1 
------
   1    
   2
   3
   4
   5
```

`sp2` returns results

```
value2
------
   4    
   5
   6
   7
   8
```

I have a table called `test` that has two columns `value1` and `value2`, how to insert `sp1` result in `value1` column and `sp2` result in `value2` column in `test` table?

I am using this

```
  insert into test 
     exec [sp1], exec [sp2]
```

It is causing an error but it is working for single value please click following link

Comment: How will you correlate the rows from the two tables? Is it okay to order by `value1` and `value2`? What do you do if one SP returns more rows than the other? Why are you even doing this at all? It really doesn't make sense for the two SPs, if they are returning separate rowsets, to be correlated in any way. Please help us understand the meaning and purpose of what you want.

Answer (score 8):

The only way I can think of is the following:

```
declare @t1 as table (id int identity(1,1), val int);
declare @t2 as table (id int identity(1,1), val int);

insert into @t1 (val)
    exec sp1;

insert into @t2 (val)
    exec sp2;

insert into test
    select t1.val, t2.val
    from @t1 t1 full outer join
         @t2 t2
         on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are functions you can do the following, pseudocode:

```
first_val = select sp1();  
second_val = select sp2();


insert into test values (first_val,second_val);
```

This **may** work as well:

```
insert into test values (select sp1(),select sp2());
```

You cannot use procedures as there is no way to return a value from a procedure.